# correct way to allocate the NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I wanted to know which is the right way to allocate an `NSMutableArray`.

```
NSMutableArray *a;
```

Where a is a class level variable.

First method is:

```
self.a = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Second method is:

```
a = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Which method is better? Can anyone please help me out in this?

Answer (score 1):

If a is a class variable, then correct way to allocate `NSMutableArray` will be creating a temporary array and assigning it to class variable, followed by releasing the temporary variable.

You can do this way:

```
NSMutableArray *temp  = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
self.a = temp;
[temp release];
```

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the property type. (Though it's in most cases a retain)
You should either use a temp value or create it in one string and send an autorelease message:
self.a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];
You must send an autorelease becuase a property increases retain count by one. This is the same as doing:

```
[self setA:array];//where array - is newly created array
```

Where:

```
 - (void)setA:(NSMutableArray *)array {
     if (array != a) {
        [a release];
        a = [array retain];//here you increased a retain count by 1
     }
}
```

You can also use an autorelease method of creation:

```
self.a = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways. But below way is good enough per me whether you are working with ARC/Non-ARC. Just make sure you have created property.

```
self.a = [NSMutableArray array];//It will return autorelease object.
```

Answer (score 0):

The difference between the methods:

1) When you use self.a ,
           You use the setter & getter methods created in the @synthesize.

2) When you use just a, 
           You bypass the accessor methods and directly modify the instance variable. (a in here).

There are two ways to look at it.

Many programmers say that you should never call the accessors from within the implementation of the object as this adds unnecessary overhead.

Some others say that you should always use the accessors, and never access the instance variable directly.

It is generally safe to use an object directly, if you are reading its value only. If you are modifying the object, you should use the accessors in order to make sure that any other objects observing that property are properly notified.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. but i getting the warning potential leak when i  use this method self.a = [NSMutableArray alloc] init]; and also i release this array in dealloc method

Answer (score 0):

The latest objective C syntax allows you to create mutable and non-mutable arrays very quickly.

The following two examples demonstrate this:

```
 NSArray *objectsToAdd = [@"Ted", @"Ned" , @"Sed"];
 NSMutableArray *objectsToAdd = [ @[@"Ted", @"Ned" , @"Sed"] mutableCopy ];
```

Answer (score -2):

```
NSMutableArray *a = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Comment: Thanks.. In my case the variable "
a" is class level variable